# Room Booking PHP concept

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm just learned the basic of `PHP`, `HTML5`, `Javascript`. And **Final Year Project** for my diploma is to create a simple guesthouse system.

The concept of the room booking that I started confused me more as i proceed.

There are the tables in my database :

1. **roomreservation** : `roomreservation_ID`,`arrival`,`departure,room_ID`
2. **room** : `room_ID`,`room_Name`,`room_Description`.

When book a `room`, `date` will be filter first. And here comes the **problem**. 
If I try

```
select room_ID, max(departure) from room reservation group by room_ID;
```

Of course this is able to pick each `room_ID` with the latest date but how do i continue for comparison with `$userinputdate`?

Noted that **Each Room only got one in quantity.**

This is the sample table I'm currently using http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1930a

And this is the code I wrote

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["btn"]))
 {   
     $sd = $_POST["starting_date"]; //get from user input
     $ed = $_POST["ending_date"]; 

     $sql="SELECT room_id FROM roominventory where departure <= '$sd' group by room_id "; //this is for roominventory table
     $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);           
     $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

     $sd1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST["starting_date"])); //convert date format
     $ed1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST["ending_date"]));
     echo "\n";

     echo nl2br("Starting Date :".$sd1."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."Ending Date :".$ed1."\n"); //display converted date format

     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
         $a = $row['room_id'];
         $result2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM room where room_id='$a'");
         while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
?>
         <body>
         <table border="solid" width="400px">
         <tr>
            <th colspan="4"><?php echo $row2["room_name"]; ?></th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">picture here</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Description: <?php echo $row2["room_desc"]; ?> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>feature here</td>
            <td>Price: <?php echo $row2["room_price"]; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo "<a href=book2.php?id=".$row2["room_id"]."&sd=".$sd."&ed=".$ed.">BOOK NOW</a>"; //pass tri-varible  ?></td>
         </tr>         
         </table>
         </body>         
<?php           
         }
     }

 }

?>
```

The downside of this code i wrote is it will filter every date in my database, even the outdated ones.

Comment: If you provide a [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/256da/8) we can find an answer much easier.
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where is `$userinputdate`? How is it used? How you're fetching data inside PHP? Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RyanVincent,  
1) I wanted to pass the `$date` that user input to all my rooms 
2) My rooms will `$display` to the user if they are free at that `$date`

Comment: @RyanVincent, is the roomreservation table above done right?